# Calculating similarities in colors in RGB

Tags: colors, rgb

I'm writing a program that hides text in the image ([Steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)).

I needed an algorithm that can calculate a pixel color to be similar to others in the vicinity. For example, [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrRSX.png).

The central pixel: the closest color to the neighborhood. But I need to get the *same* **R G B** value. For example: 200, 200, 200.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. Can you explain more clearly, or maybe with an example?